# Facebook OAuth for Drupal 7

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth

I have installed the FACEBOOK OAuth for drupal7. however when i connect the f connect button it takes me to facebook site but in the middle of the page an error is displayed which is:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given
>   URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Why is this and how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into app setting in facebook and in the field "App Domains" add the domain of your site. Be sure to use subdomain if the website is on subdomain. Means that if your site is on example.com you should add example.com in the field. If it resides on mysite.example.com you should add mysite.example.com.

Comment: what if its on my localhost

Comment: It's the same. Just add your virtual host. Not sure if it will work with adding localhost although there is no reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

`API Error Code: 191` means that the `redirect_uri` hasn't been set correctly.

Make sure that the `redirect_uri` contains the site URL or the canvas URL as you defined in your application settings.